# What`s wrong in MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT n.nid, n.title, c.field_news_date_value, 
       c.field_news_short_text_value, c.field_news_short_text_format 
FROM node n, term_data m,  term_node p 
INNER JOIN content_type_news c 
   ON c.nid = n.nid AND c.vid = n.vid 
WHERE n.type='news' AND n.status=1 
ORDER BY c.field_news_date_value DESC.
```

I am getting an error

> Unknown column 'n.nid' in 'on clause'.

Comment: That mean in "node AS n" is no filed called n.nid ---  "SELECT n.nid"

Comment: Just to confirm is it an oversight to add term_data and term_node tables in the query because they are not used anywhere?

Comment: There's a AND directly after the ON... can you do that?

Comment: its is ambiguous to use `JOIN` while multiple table in `FROM` clause

Comment: what is the usage of `term_data m,  term_node p ` in Query?

Answer (score 1):

I think query must be like this. ( assuming there must be columns, name `nid` and `vid` in both tables)

**Note :** it is ambiguous to use use multiple table in `FROM` clause when we are using `JOIN`

```
SELECT n.nid, n.title, c.field_news_date_value, 
       c.field_news_short_text_value, c.field_news_short_text_format 
FROM node n
INNER JOIN content_type_news c 
ON c.nid = n.nid AND c.vid = n.vid 
WHERE n.type='news' AND n.status=1 
ORDER BY c.field_news_date_value DESC.
```

Comment: +1 but the error the OP gets is not from ambiguity. It's because the query is parsed as: `node n , term_data m , (term_node p INNER JOIN content_type_news c ON c.nid = n.nid AND c.vid = n.vid) ...` and the there is no `n.nid` defined inside that parenthesis.

Comment: @ypercube can we use multiple table in FROM clause while using JOIN?

Comment: I wouldn't combine `,` with `JOIN` but you can.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT n.nid, n.title, c.field_news_date_value, c.field_news_short_text_value, c.field_news_short_text_format 
FROM term_data m, term_node p, node n INNER JOIN content_type_news c 
ON c.nid = n.nid AND c.vid = n.vid 
WHERE n.type='news' AND n.status=1 
ORDER BY c.field_news_date_value DESC
```

Basically, moved `node n` near to the `INNER JOIN` operator.

Comment: New error - "Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_1f8_0.MYI'; try to repair it".

Comment: Looks like the query is now correct. For the new error, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/repair-table.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `AS` in the query. Please use the following query :

```
SELECT 
 n.nid, n.title, 
 c.field_news_date_value, 
 c.field_news_short_text_value, 
 c.field_news_short_text_format 
FROM 
 node as n, term_data as m,  term_node as p 
INNER JOIN 
 content_type_news c ON c.nid = n.nid AND c.vid = n.vid 
WHERE 
 n.type='news' 
 AND n.status=1 
ORDER BY 
 c.field_news_date_value DESC
```

Comment: Try this... it should work,
SELECT n.nid, n.title, c.field_news_date_value, c.field_news_short_text_value, c.field_news_short_text_format 
FROM node as n, term_data as m,  term_node as p 
INNER JOIN content_type_news as c 
   ON c.nid = n.nid AND c.vid = n.vid 
WHERE n.type='news' AND n.status=1 
ORDER BY c.field_news_date_value DESC.